# How to create a HttpConnection implementation in Java ME using SocketConnection?

Tags: sockets, java-me, httpconnection

In the Java ME platform that I am using I have only SocketConnection class to connect to a distant server. For example I can create a connection to a server socket on the given ip using `Connector.open("socket://"+ip+":"+port)`.

What I want is to implement an HttpConnection that will use http protocol, a url and port 80 as parameters. I imagine it will be something like `Connector.open("http://www.google.com:80)` to be able to send GET, POST, DELETE, PUT requests to the server afterwards.

Is there a way to get the ip via url address and then connect to this ip using http protocol? Or if it isn't supported by my platform, then I have to stick to using sockets? I know my question can seem a little abstract, so ask if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stick to using sockets. If the Java ME platform that you are using have only `SocketConnection`, a call to `Connector.open("http://www.google.com:80")` will throw an exception.

Comment: Indeed it does throw an exception that indicates that the platform doesn't support the type of connection specified. What about using `Connector.open("socket://www.google.com:80")`? I thought it could work but I get `IOException: cannot open socket using DNS`.

Comment: Your platform is also restrictive with Domain Name Service and you will have to replace www.google.com with an IP.